# shell validating the input has three numbers separated by commas

Tags: bash, shell

How can i validate a variable in shell has only three whole numbers separated by ,. Like below

```
23543,24543,245 ->true
34535,435436    ->false
f,34545,34656   -> false
```

Comment: use a regular expression.

Comment: `^[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+$`

Comment: bash extended glob patterns work as well: `[[ $1 == +([0-9]),+([0-9]),+([0-9]) ]]`

Comment: `var='23543,24543,245'; IFS=, read -r n1 n2 n3 <<<"$var"; [[ "$n1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ && "$n2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ && "$n3" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; echo $?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash regex:

```
$ var=f,34545,34656
$ [[ $var =~ ^[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+$ ]] && echo true || echo false
false
```